# Entity Framework 4.1, DBContext, how to reuse transaction among connections

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any way to  reuse a transaction among different connections without recurring to DTC?
I can't figure out how to do this.

```
using (TransactionScope ...
{
    using (var db1 = new modelXEntities())
    {
        db1.Database.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current); ???   
        db1.SaveChanges(); ==>error

        using (var db2 = new modelYEntities())
        {
            db2.Database.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current); ???    
            db2.SaveChanges(); ==>error
```

Error: The underlying provider failed on Open...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have single transaction for multiple connection you must use distributed transaction = MSDTC. The reason is that coordinating transaction among multiple transactional resources requires special handling (two-phase commit). All transactional resources must communicate with separate process coordinating the transaction. That is what MSDTC (MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator) provides.